# What is the equivalent of ASP.NET's [Authorize] in PHP/CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, codeigniter

In ASP.NET MVC, we use the [Authorize] attribute on a controller and put

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Accounts/Login" defaultUrl="~/Accounts/Login" />
</authentication>
```

on web.config to redirect requests to login page when not logged in.

Is there a similar way of doing redirects when not logged in on Codeigniter?

Comment: No, not build in, but there are several authentication libraries like ion auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a similar way of doing redirects when not logged in on Codeigniter?"

You could just check for a session/cookie. If it's not found the user isn't logged in.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')) 
{
    redirect('login');
}
```

You could include this in the Controller constructor, to secure that controller. Or just put it in certain methods.

Hope this helps.